# JQuery - show only one if the same id and also add it on weeks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this sample data:

```
[{"id":"2", "weeks":2}, {"id":"2", "weeks":4}, {"id":3, "weeks":7}]
```

I wanted that I will only show one if id is redundant but add all of the weeks that the id's had

My Attempt:

```
var data = [{"id":"2", "weeks":2}, {"id":"2", "weeks":4}, {"id":3, "weeks":7}];
var weeks = 0;
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    weeks += data[i].weeks;
}
```

Desired output

```
[{"id":"2", "weeks":6}, {"id":3, "weeks":7}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce()` with `Object.values()`. Group your data based on `id` and add the `weeks` for repeating `id` in an object. Take the values from the object using `Object.values()`.

```js
const data = [{"id":"2", "weeks":2}, {"id":"2", "weeks":4}, {"id":3, "weeks":7}],
      result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,{id,weeks}) => {
        r[id] = r[id] || {id, weeks : 0};
        r[id].weeks += weeks;
        return r;
      },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) combined with [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) or [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) based on the number of repeated elements with same `id`

Code:

```js
const data = [{"id":"2", "weeks":2}, {"id":"2", "weeks":4}, {"id":3, "weeks":7}];
const result = data
  .reduce((a, c) => {
    a.temp[c.id] = ++a.temp[c.id] || 1;
    a.temp[c.id] === 1
      ? a.array.push(c)
      : a.array.find(item => item.id == a.temp[c.id]).weeks += c.weeks;
    return a;
  }, {temp: {}, array: []})
  .array;

console.log(result);
```